# a2ensite does not create log files

Tags: bash, apache2

I have a simple bash script which should generate Apache **site.conf** file and then run `a2ensite site.name` 
Everything works fine but a2ensite does not generate log files automatically. Then when I run `sudo systemctl reload apache2` it throws me an error **Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/www/site.name/'** Bash file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Write url without www and http prefixes: ' url

template=$(</home/Camo/custom-scripts/apache/site-template.conf)
# Next line is string substitution
template=("${template//__URL__/$url}")

configFile=${url}'.conf'
configDirPath="/etc/apache2/sites-available/"
wwwDirPath="/var/www/html/$url"

mkdir $wwwDirPath
chown -R www-data:www-data $wwwDirPath
chmod 644 -R $wwwDirPath 

echo "$template" > $configDirPath$configFile

sudo a2ensite ${configFile}
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

and here is site.cong file created by previous script

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com
        ServerName camo.publicvm.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/camo.publicvm.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/camo.publicvm.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

everything looks ok so why are log files missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Am I right log files are not generated automaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log files are not generated automatically, so you will have to create them manually:

```
touch ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/error.log
touch ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/access.log
```

And don't forget changing its ownership:

```
chown root.adm ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/error.log
chown root.adm ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www/camo.publicvm.com/access.log
```

Then check if everything looks fine and if it does, reload `apache2` service:

```
apachectl configtest
systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: Yes I though apache will generate it automatically. But no....